# BufferedImage para BufferedImage ou salvar BufferedImage como um blob no banco de dados

Tags: blob

olá, hoje estou trabalhando com o facebook messenger e eles me enviam as imagens uploads via url, dessa forma ->

> BufferedImage  image = ImageIO.read(url);

e eu preciso salvar isso em uma coluna do meu banco no formato blob.

em um chat web eu já tinha um serviço que me enviava imagens no formato MultipartFile e eu conseguia fazer todo o processo de salvar no banco de dados.

já procurei como converter BufferedImage para MultipartFile  mas até agora sem respostas.

Comment: Fala Durazzo Blz ?
Tenta ver se isso funciona !!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163648/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-a-multipart-file-without-saving-file-to-disk
Abraço

Comment: Fala Durazzo Blz ?
Tenta ver se isso funciona !!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163648/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-a-multipart-file-without-saving-file-to-disk
Abraço

Answer (score 0):

A resolução do meu problema acabou sendo simples, 
Resolução->

```
  BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(url);

  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", bos);
  byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
  Blob blob = new SerialBlob(data);
```